# Pattern Match Username with Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a pattern match a string that has the following rules:

- No more than 15 characters
- Must have a full stop in between two strings
- Digits can only be at the end of the string
- Only 2 digits allowed

**Example Fails**

- .asdfa
- dadad.
- 1apple.pear
- apple.pear123

**Example Success**

- apple.pear
- ben.peach12

Edit for confusion: 
This is for HTML Input Patterns

I have tried the following 
`((([A-Za-z]+[.][A-Za-z]+){1,15})([0-9]{0,2}))` 
But it does not stop at 15 characters

And this 
`([A-Za-z.]{1,15})([0-9]{0,2})` 
But it matches if there is no.

Comment: Your question does not contain an actual  question. What have you tried yet? Where are you stuck? What do mean when you say "I'm trying to make a pattern match a username"? Are you like trying to build a validation system or do you want to scrape a name that matches this pattern? Is this a Javascript question?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck updated for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead for this problem.

```
(?=.{1,15}$)([a-z]+\.[a-z]+[0-9]{0,2})
```

Taken from [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but
>   then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match.
>   That is why they are called "assertions". They do not consume
>   characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible
>   or not.

The first part of this regular expression checks the length of your string, but - as stated above - no characters are consumed at all. So after that you can do your username checks you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it all at once.

First, breaking down a problem into smaller pieces is just good for maintaining it anyway.

Second, if you ever decide you want to change the requirements, you can do that much more easily.

Third, when a user submits a username, you can tell them *exactly* what about it you don't like. Specifying a single validation rule that fails is way better UX than just saying it's invalid.

So with all that said... HTML's `pattern` attribute may not be the best method for validating such complex rules. Instead, you should use JavaScript to validate (and again on the server) and present custom validity text as needed.

```
input.onchange = function() {
    if( this.value.length > 15) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Max length: 15 characters");
        return;
    }
    var parts = this.value.split(".");
    if( parts.length != 2 || !parts[0] || !parts[1]) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Must have two parts separated by a dot");
        return;
    }
    if( this.value.replace(/\d+$/,'').match(/\d/)) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Digits can only appear at the end");
        return;
    }
    if( this.value.match(/\d{3}$/)) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Max of two digits at the end");
        return;
    }
    this.setCustomValidity(""); // valid
};
```